# Problem In pycharm (Github Copilot is not working correctly)

Tags: python, pycharm, github-copilot

When I change anything it just loads for a while and sometimes it keeps loading.

[image]

it only works when I do it manually

[image]

Note:I already tried to reinstall the plugin but still not working